# The syntax of update is showing error on running

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am using update + set + where command and it's showing an error. It says something about going to options< preferences < SQL editor < my safe update... I un-ticked the safe update, still no change.

The syntax I use is:

```
update student 
set major = 'English' 
where major = 'eng';
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please also update your question to show the actual error

Comment: i am using mysql (workbench)